# Django says SECRET_KEY must not be empty

Tags: python, django

I imported a Django project from a repo, and when I try to make the migrations with 
`python manage.py makemigrations`, I get the following exception:

```
File "C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

After looking online, I read that adding `from base import *` to `__init__.py` could solve it, but it just sends a different error:

```
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  File "C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\static.py", line 22, in static
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Empty static prefix not permitted
```

My 'base.py' settings do have `SECRET_KEY = 'my_key_value'` , and my 'local.py' settings first line is `from.base import *`, and it doesn't override the SECRET_KEY, so I don't know why it says the SECRET_KEY is empty. I do not see any other settings through the project, so I don't know where else to look, I'm new to django, so I'm a bit lost here and have been stuck for a few days.

In my 'wsgi.py' file, as well, it includes the line

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'quiniela.settings')
```

And in 'quiniela.settings' I have the 'init.py', 'base.py' and 'local.py'

Comment: Maybe you have a `SECRET_KEY=''` in your `local.py` that overrides the base settings?

Comment: No, I did search for that, but there's no override in the local.py.

Comment: from.base import * - is that a typo ? That "." dot between from and base ?

Comment: Are you storing your secret key in another file? That part is unclear to me

Comment: From the second error I think it might be failing to find your settings file altogether.

Comment: The 'from .base import *' has a space after the 'from', and it doesn't seem to be a typo.

Comment: In my wsgi.py file, it includes 'os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'quiniela.settings')', and in 'quiniela.settings' I have the '__init__.py', 'base.py' and 'local.py'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing 
`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'quiniela.settings')`
to `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'quiniela.settings.local')`
in my manage.py file, but only there, not in wsgi.py or changing anything else.